# Python: interpolate dataset to create a global map

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, interpolation, grids-graticules, multipoint

I have a NetCDF dataset ([this](https://mega.nz/file/mOwlVAYK#kvEkCdJBaR7bLtXc2MFHDDwt8Va8SBhCnX-DhiHpeZ8)) with values for the world's oceans. The measurements are in the form of unevenly spaced points:
[image]

Now I want to extract some values at specific locations. My problem is, what happens if my point of interest does not fall exactly into one of the points on the dataset? I thought I should create a raster file with data interpolated all over the oceans (and leave NaN for the land), and then I could sample whatever point I like using e.g. rasterio. Makes sense?

If so, how can I do that using Python? I guess it will involve these steps:

- interpolate values
- set a resolution for the raster
- export the data as a GeoTiff

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: as a remark, I don't know if your variable of interest is there but there are already existing products in tif https://bio-oracle.org/  . Otherwise you can interpolate with scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html but it is not trivial because you must select a model that is suited to your data structure.

Comment: Thank you @radouxju I have added a link to the file in case it helps

Comment: @radouxju - What exactly do you mean by selecting a model that is suited to my data structure?

Comment: there are many methods to perform an interpolation, so you must understand the spatial autocorrelation to use the best method. You don't interpolate current direction and water temperature the same way. If your data change smoothly, then most existing methods will work "well enough" but sometimes it isn't